# sp_BlitzFirst - option to save more than only SQL Server PerfMon stats?

Tags: sp-blitzfirst

First, I can't say enough good things about the FirstResponders kit. It's my "Go To" anytime something seems funny on the SQL servers.

I'm also using sp_BlitzFirst to capture data to tables for my own reporting.

Q: For Perfmon stats from sp_BlitzFirst, is there an option or parameter to capture additional perfmon stats? I'm thinking maybe stuff like:

- Processor "% Processor time", "Queue Length"
- maybe some Physical Disk values
- also curious about Network Interface as we have a couple large queries coming from other servers.

sp_BlitzFirst version 7.9999 (20201114), SQL Server 2016.

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Q: For Perfmon stats from sp_BlitzFirst, is there an option or parameter to capture additional perfmon stats?

Not at the moment! They're all hard-coded into the proc. If there are additional ones you'd like, they'd have to be added to the list. You can make that suggestion [over on GitHub](http://firstresponderkit.org/).